# Get Driver Version using Selenium with C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, firefoxdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am testing with C# & Selenium & Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver (Nu-GET Package, Version 2.44.0). Now I am searching for a Method which gives me the actual Version of the current runnig driver.

Is there someone who can help me here I found this posts already but none of these helped: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556163/get-browser-version-using-selenium-webdriver
https://mashtips.com/get-system-os-browser-version-java-selenium-webdriver/

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the actual version of the driver, e.g. the version of chromedriver.exe:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("./");
ICapabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
Console.WriteLine((capabilities.GetCapability("chrome") as Dictionary<string, object>)["chromedriverVersion"]);
```

This returns: 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72)

The `capabilities` object looks like this:

```
{
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "chrome": {
    "chromedriverVersion": "73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72)",
    "userDataDir": "C:\\Users\\NIELSV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir7524_3294"
  },
  "platform": "Windows NT",
  "version": "73.0.3683.103"
}
```

If you want to access deeper nested items you need to cast it to a `Dictionary` first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the version of the ChromeDriver (this is different than the version of Chrome), it's a returned capability in chrome.chromedriverversion as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chrome uses different string  that you should use to get the versins, for Firefox is "browserVersion" and for Chrome is "version".
`browserCapabilities.GetCapability("browserVersion")` - return the Firefox version,
`browserCapabilities.GetCapability("version")` - return the Chrome version.You can make a method that check for the one or the second string and get the version of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

`((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getVersion()` should work for all browsers.  I am not sure when this change took place, but when you examine the `Capabilities` class, it is obvious why this is the case:

```
default String getVersion() {
  return String.valueOf(Optional.ofNullable(getCapability("browserVersion")).orElse(
    Optional.ofNullable(getCapability("version")).orElse("")));
}
```

Comment: getCapabilities() is not a method on RemoteWebDriver

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal I stand corrected. The solution I provided is a Java solution, not C#.

Comment: The question is about C#, see topic/summary. This might be confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(AppPath);


        ICapabilities capabilities = ((ChromeDriver)driver). Capabilities;
        Console.WriteLine((capabilities.GetCapability("chrome") as Dictionary<string, object>)["chromedriverVersion"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetBrowserVersion() 
{ 
    string thisbrowserversion=""; 
    
    switch (ThisAppSettings.browserAppSetting.toLower())
    {
       case "chrome":
         thisbrowserversion = ((RemoteWebDriver)thisbrowser).Capabilities.GetCapability("version").ToString(); 
         break;
       case "firefox":
         thisbrowserversion = ((RemoteWebDriver)thisbrowser).Capabilities.GetCapability("browserVersion").ToString();
         break;
       default:
         // Throw exception stating unsupported browser

    }
    return thisbrowserversion; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Rather than just posting code, can you also explain how/why this is different or better than the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your reply! Now I am using this workaround.

```
public static string GetBrowserVersion() 
{ 
    string thisbrowserversion; 
    if (ThisAppSettings.browserAppSetting == "Chrome") 
    { 
        thisbrowserversion = ((RemoteWebDriver)thisbrowser).Capabilities.GetCapability("version").ToString();     
    } 
    else 
    { 
        thisbrowserversion = ((RemoteWebDriver)thisbrowser).Capabilities.GetCapability("browserVersion").ToString(); 
    } 
    return thisbrowserversion; 
}
```

Works fine. The Datatype "RemoteWebDriver" was the critical thing.

Comment: You don't need this workaround anymore. The `Capabilities` class already implemented this default behavior.